# js Напишите функцию, которая возвращает последнюю цифру числа

Tags: javascript

Напишите функцию, которая возвращает последнюю цифру данного целого числа в виде английского слова. Примеры: 512 -> «два»

```js
function lastNumberNamerMap() {
  let map = new Map();

  map.set(1, 'один');
  map.set(2, 'два');
  map.set(3, 'три');
  map.set(4, 'четыре');
  map.set(5, 'пять');
  map.set(6, 'шесть');
  map.set(7, 'семь');
  map.set(8, 'восемь');
  map.set(9, 'девять');

  let number = 324;
  let lastNumber = number % 10;

  console.log(map.get(lastNumber));
}

lastNumberNamerMap();
```

Не могу понять, где ошибка :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function lastNumberNamerMap() {
  let map = new Map();

  map.set(0, 'ноль');
  map.set(1, 'один');
  map.set(2, 'два');
  map.set(3, 'три');
  map.set(4, 'четыре');
  map.set(5, 'пять');
  map.set(6, 'шесть');
  map.set(7, 'семь');
  map.set(8, 'восемь');
  map.set(9, 'девять');

  let number = 324;
  let lastNumber = number % 10;

  console.log(map.get(lastNumber));
}

lastNumberNamerMap();
```

---

```js
function lastNumberNamerMap(number) {
  let map = new Map();

  map.set(0, 'ноль');
  map.set(1, 'один');
  map.set(2, 'два');
  map.set(3, 'три');
  map.set(4, 'четыре');
  map.set(5, 'пять');
  map.set(6, 'шесть');
  map.set(7, 'семь');
  map.set(8, 'восемь');
  map.set(9, 'девять');

  let lastNumber = number % 10;

  return map.get(lastNumber);
}

console.log(lastNumberNamerMap(542));
```

Comment: ... и еще добавить в map цифру 0

Comment: Какие дурацкие ошибки)
Не вызвала функцию и ноль забыла...
Спасибо!

Comment: Alia Tempora, Вы можете отметить ответ как "решающий Вашу проблему". Это такая галочка слева от ответа. Таким образом, Вы не только отметите ответ как полезный, но и поднимите свой рейтинг на сайте.

Comment: @AliaTempora `Map`, кстати, вполне легально можно заменть на обычный массив `["ноль", "один", "два", ...]`

Answer (score -1):

Та, на

```js
const lastIntOfNum=(num=0)=>{
    num = `${num}`;
    num = num[num.length - 1];
    return ['ноль', 'один', 'два', 'три', 'четыре', 'пять', 'шесть', 'семь', 'восемь', 'девять'][+num];
};

console.log(lastIntOfNum(1));
console.log(lastIntOfNum(100));
console.log(lastIntOfNum(105));
console.log(lastIntOfNum(76554));
console.log(lastIntOfNum('as01'));
```